# Google Earth integration inside Adobe AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- Is it possible ( and how if it is ) to integrate Google Earth inside Adobe AIR application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Earth uses a plugin and the only plugin supported by the HTML Side of Adobe AIR is Flash Player; then the answer is you cannot use Google Earth inside an Adobe AIR Application.

Comment: It seems that Google Earth is JavaScript 'plugin', however there are various reports that its usage failed in mx:HTML. I guess air's browser is not a browser that  supports 'NPAPI with npruntime extensions'(from google earth documentation).

Comment: @user1875642 The Wikipedia entry on Google Earth states that Google Earth uses a browser plugin.  I don't know how it is implemented; but I Guess--theoretically--it could be done in JavaScript.  If that is not what you're referring to; I don't understand what "JavaSCript Plugin" means in your context.  I believe the only plugins supported by Adobe AIR [for Desktop] are Flash Player and [I believe] a PDF Viewer.

Comment: I mean that today many JS scripts that are inserted into specific pages with the help of browser are treated like plugins(for example Google Chrome will name your GreaseMonkey script 'plugin'), and only few of them use functionality that is not available in page context. As mx:HTML supports javascript, then importing such script in a page may help.  Another interesting question if air mobile which uses native browser can use its plugins.

Comment: @user1875642 GreaseMonkey is a browser extension; not a plugin.  I believe they have completely different architectures.  Greasemonkey, as I understood it, will inject JavaScript into a page you're loading.  That is very different than a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

No, as Google Earth has no AS3 API for this (AFAIK you can only integrate it into your website by using a browser plugin).

Comment: An Adobe AIR Application is a desktop or mobile application; not a browser based application.

Comment: I just mentioned the only possible way of integrating GE somewhere. Sure browser plugin app is not an Air one. :)